# Youtube embed - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry to ask this question that may seem easy for some but I'm pulling my hair since this morning for such a small thing.

I installed the gem Youtube_embeb (https://github.com/shir/youtube-embed/).

That allow to post a youtube link in iframe ... but it does not work!

I have a software form with a youtube_url field.

I do not understand because when I add:

```
require 'youtube_embed'
```

in my javascript.js, i have an error ...

```
couldn't find file 'youtube_embed' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Thx for you help.

Comment: You're not supposed to add that line to application.js. It looks like ruby code (and you probably need single quotes there, not backticks)

Comment: I tested everything with the other quotes also ... and I put the require in my controller, javascript, ... everywhere ... there is no information on this topic on the internet.
I do not understand where to insert this require ...

Comment: You need to add `require 'youtube_embed'` at the top of the file only in controller or module or model where you want use video object

Comment: Thank you for your answers but unfortunately it does not work either ... nothing is displayed ...

I have been busy for 5 hours on this problem and there is no information on the internet: '(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem seems simple, in the documentation it doesn't say that you need to add to application.js anything, if you see at the code of the gem, it doesn't have any js file.

so just add to your gemfile this line

```
gem 'youtube_embed'
```

run bundle install

and add this one to your application_helper for example so you can have that helper available on every view of the application. so add in application helper, this line

```
require 'youtube_embed'
```

Make sure to stop and start again the server, just to be sure that it loads the gem, and then you can just call on the view where you want to show the video, this line

```
<%= YoutubeEmbed::Video.iframe('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD_e7T5WCqw') %>
```

and it just create some html with an iframe to show the video. you just have to add it where you want it to show and change the url for the video you want.

I tested the gem and it's working. just with those 3 lines.

having in mind that the gem is working, I can still suggest a simpler solution, remove the gems, add this helper

https://gist.github.com/a-barbieri/a93281cd5c01025664e5cbd781cd917c

following the instructions and then you can just call to

```
<%= get_video_iframe('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD_e7T5WCqw') %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I still can not post the video in the show ...

I started but I feel like I have already done much more complicated ... I have a problem with the documentation of this gem ... I do not understand ..

Comment: Ok I added more info and another solution that is simpler for you, hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much ! But for the first solution I have a problem .. nevertheless I followed the same approach ... I receive an error: "uninitialized constant YoutubeEmbed :: Video" ...

But everything works perfectly with the second! Your second solution is much more practical.

Thank you very much xploshioOn !!